# jquery live filter based on content and tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-filter

I'm using This jQuery live filter plugin:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.liveFilter = function(inputEl, filterEl, options){
        var defaults = {
            filterChildSelector: null,
            filter: function(el, val){
                return $(el).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
            },
            before: function(){},
            after: function(){}
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        var el = $(this).find(filterEl);
        if (options.filterChildSelector) el = el.find(options.filterChildSelector);

        var filter = options.filter;
        $(inputEl).keyup(function(){
            var val = $(this).val();
            var contains = el.filter(function(){
                return filter(this, val);
            });
            var containsNot = el.not(contains);
            if (options.filterChildSelector){
                contains = contains.parents(filterEl);
                containsNot = containsNot.parents(filterEl).hide();
            }

            options.before.call(this, contains, containsNot);

            contains.show();
            containsNot.hide();

            if (val === '') {
                contains.show();
                containsNot.show();
            }

            options.after.call(this, contains, containsNot);
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

What I want to do is to filter based on tags too, so the list gets filtered by data-tag attribute of each element.
This is how html looks:

```
<li><a href="#" data-tags="tag1">content</a></li>
```

Currently it filters based on content of a tags, I need data-tags to be involved in filter too.

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/BR7KE/

Comment: @Andreas ...What I want to do is to filter based on tags too... I need data-tags to be involved in filter too , I have mentioned what I want twice. Read the question !

Comment: SO is a site to ask questions about a particular problem not a code request site... And I see no question so I've ask about the problem you have.

Comment: @Andreas The question is HOW TO GET AN ATTRIBUTE INVOLVED IN SEARCH ,If you can't answer it , doesn't mean the question is wrong.

Comment: @Andreas And the downvote is for?? SO is a site to solve problems, YOU by down voting are abusing the privilege and reducing the chance of this problem to be seen by the people who really are trying to help here. SO is already great , but with less people like you It would have been even more cool and comfortable for people to discuss their problems without having to deal with this kind of horrible attitude.

Comment: No down vote from me... Not for a "question" like yours. There has to be much less effort or ignorance to be down voted by me - beleave it or not. And for your complaint. You just wrote "I want..." No "I've tried... but have problems to achieve..." or "How to do...". And yelling is no good attitude either.

Comment: @Andreas So you are arguing with me because I said what I want to do is ... blah blah? the way you are trying for justification is just funny, first you say it's not a particular problem and now you are criticizing me because of using "I want to do..." instead of "How to do" ?? Beleave!!! it, you gotta learn some English before you criticize others for the words they use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pass filter options to the plugins where you return the elements filtering by text and data-tag

try this

```
$('#livefilter-list').liveFilter('#livefilter-input', 'li', {
      filterChildSelector: 'a',
      filter: function(el, val){
             return $(el).data('tags') == val || $(el).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
      },  

});
```

**no need to modify the core plugins...**

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/BR7KE/7/)

Comment: Well, Thanks, can you please teach me how to add even more attributes like data-categories

Comment: as like filter from data-categories....then  return what you needed inside filter function seperated by `||` ..example...`return $(el).data('tags') == val || $(el).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(val.toUpperCase()) >= 0 || $(el).data('categories') == val ;`

Comment: anyways ... welcome... glad it helped